# $xy$ itself square in this particular logic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logic

I would like to know the solution or procedure to find the exact analysis/solution of one of my observation. let $x = a^2$ and $y = b^2$, then can we express $xy$ (concatenation of $x$ and $y$) as square of some integer?
example $16 = 4^2$ and $9 = 3^2 \implies 169$ can be expressed as $13^2$.
How to find such cited above numbers? other than $16$ and $9$, how many are existing? and how to find them? could you explain please...
Thanks in advance!
Naroza

Comment: I believe by $xy$ OP means concatenation of $x$ and $y$, from the example given.

Comment: @milind! you are absolutely correct. here x and y are concatenation.

Comment: @milind! thank you so much for editing my post.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions to the Pell equation $x^2-10y^2=1$ (you can replace $1$ by $4$ or $9$), so there are infinitely many solutions to your initial problem (concatenate $y^2$ and $1^2$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the Pell equation $s^2-10t^2=1$. There are infinitely many positive integer solutions, given by $$s=\frac{(19+6\sqrt{10})^n+(19-6\sqrt{10})^n}{2}, t=\frac{(19+6\sqrt{10})^n-(19-6\sqrt{10})^n}{2\sqrt{10}}, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

Now take $x=t^2, y=1$, then when we concatenate $x$ and $y$, we get $\overline{xy}=10x+y=10t^2+1=s^2$.

Examples:

$n=1$ gives $s=19, t=6, x=6^2=36, y=1, \overline{xy}=361=19^2$.

$n=2$ gives $s=721, t=228, x=228^2=51984, y=1, \overline{xy}=519841=721^2$.

$n=3$ gives $s=27379, t=8658, x=8658^2=74960964, y=1, \overline{xy}=749609641=27379^2$.

We can similarly get solutions to $s^2-10t^2=9$, then take $x=t^2, y=9$.

**Edit:** Consider any perfect square $y=c^2$ with $2k-1$ digits, then there are infinitely many positive integer solutions to the Pell equation $s^2-10^{2k-1}t^2=c^2$, some of which are given by (not necessarily all solutions)

$$s=c\left(\frac{(s_0+t_0\sqrt{10^{2k-1}})^n+(s_0-t_0\sqrt{10^{2k-1}})^n}{2}\right)$$
$$t=c\left(\frac{(s_0+t_0\sqrt{10^{2k-1}})^n-(s_0-t_0\sqrt{10^{2k-1}})^n}{2\sqrt{10^{2k-1}}}\right), n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

where $(s_0, t_0)$ is the fundamental solution to the Pell equation $s^2-10^{2k-1}t^2=1$.

For example, consider $y=11^2=121$, then $(39480499, 1248483)$ is the fundamental solution to the Pell equation $s^2-1000t^2=1$. We then have the following family of solutions for the Pell equation $s^2-1000t^2=121$:

$$s=11\left(\frac{(39480499+1248483\sqrt{1000})^n+(39480499-1248483\sqrt{1000})^n}{2}\right)$$
$$t=11\left(\frac{(39480499+1248483\sqrt{1000})^n-(39480499-1248483\sqrt{1000})^n}{2\sqrt{1000}}\right), n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

For example, when $n=1$, we have $s=11(39480499)=434285489, t=11(1248483)=13733313, x=13733313^2=188603885955969, y=121, \overline{xy}=188603885955969121=434285489^2$.

**Edit 2:** Let us consider the case when $y=c^2$ has $2k$ digits (so $10^{2k-1} \leq c^2=y <10^{2k}$ so $10^{k-1}\sqrt{10}<c<10^k$). Then we want $m^2=\overline{xy}=10^{2k}x+y=10^{2k}a^2+c^2$, so we get a Pythagorean triplet. It is easy to see that for fixed $y$ (and hence fixed $c$), there are finitely many solutions.

Note that if $x=a^2, y=c^2$ satisfy $\overline{xy}=m^2$, then $x=a^2, y=(10c)^2$ satisfy $\overline{xy}=(10m)^2$. It therefore suffices to consider the case where $10 \nmid c$. (and then multiply $c$ by $10^l$ afterwards) Also $x=(ia)^2, y=(ic)^2$ satisfy $\overline{xy}=(im)^2$.

Suppose that $\gcd(c, 10^ka)=1$. Then we have a primitive Pythagorean triplet, so we have $c=s^2-t^2, 10^ka=2st, m=s^2+t^2, s, t \in \mathbb{Z}^+, s \not \equiv t \pmod{2}$. We get the following family of solutions (not all solutions):

$$s=5(10^{k-1}), t=s-1=5(10^{k-1})-1, a=t=5(10^{k-1})-1$$
$$c=s^2-t^2=s^2-(s-1)^2=2s-1=10^k-1$$
$$m=s^2+t^2=s^2+(s-1)^2=2s^2-2s+1=5(10^{2k-1})-10^k+1$$

We now multiply $c$ by $10^l$, and we get:

$$a=5(10^{k-1})-1, c=10^l(10^k-1), m=10^l(5(10^{2k-1})-10^k+1)$$
$$x=a^2=(5(10^{k-1})-1)^2, y=c^2=10^{2l}(10^k-1)^2, m=10^l(5(10^{2k-1})-10^k+1)$$

Examples:

When $k=l=1$, we have $x=(5(10^0)-1)^2=16, y=10^2(10^1-1)^2=8100, m=10(5(10^1)-10^1+1)=410, \overline{xy}=168100=410^2$.

When $k=2, l=0$, we have $x=(5(10^1)-1)^2=2401, y=(10^2-1)^2=9801, m=(5(10^3)-10^2+1)=4901, \overline{xy}=24019801=4901^2$.

Comment: ! can you generalize the same without taking pell equation directly?

Comment: @Naroza_lary_sai Suppose we fix $y$, and $y$ has $2k$ digits, then we have $x=a^2, m^2=\overline{xy}=10^{2k}x+y$ so $c^2=y=m^2-10^{2k}x=m^2-(10^ka)^2$, which has finitely many solutions for $m, a$. If $y$ has $2k-1$ digits, the problem reduces to finding solutions of the Pell equation $s^2-10^{2k-1}t^2=y=c^2$, as shown in my updated answer. If you want to avoid Pell equation, you might want to look at the case where $y$ has $2k$ digits. In that case we get Pythagorean triplets.

Comment: ! can you discuss the case of 2k digits please...